# Swift Eureka - capture MultivaluedSection delete action

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I am using swift [Eureka library](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) with MultivaluedSection component. I want to capture when a user delete a row and update my application state. I took a look at examples, they show how to enable delete action but none of them provides the ability to capture the delete action Do you know how to do it?

code from example:

```
class MultivaluedOnlyDeleteController: FormViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.isEditing = false
        let nameList = ["family", "male", "female", "client"]

        let section = MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: .Delete, footer: "you can swipe to delete when table.isEditing = false (Not Editing)")


        for tag in nameList {
            section <<< TextRow {
                            $0.placeholder = "Tag Name"
                            $0.value = tag
                        }
        }


        let section2 =  MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: .Delete, footer: "")
        for _ in 1..<4 {
            section2 <<< PickerInlineRow<String> {
                            $0.title = "Tap to select"
                            $0.value = "client"
                            $0.options = nameList
                         }
        }

        editButton.title = tableView.isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit"
        editButton.target = self
        editButton.action = #selector(editPressed(sender:))

        form    +++

                section

                +++

                section2
    }

    func editPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
        tableView.setEditing(!tableView.isEditing, animated: true)
        editButton.title = tableView.isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Core.swift file you need to change this function :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

from public to open, then you can use this function in your view controller.

[image: usage in View Controller]

Comment: That's the right approach. I found someone who already forked out the library to perform the same change: pod 'Eureka', :git => 'git@github.com:Laptopmini/Eureka.git'

Answer (score 0):

Just submitted a [PR on GitHub](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/pull/1136) but until it is approved feel free to use [my forked repository](https://github.com/AdamStreet/Eureka/tree/multivaluedsection-delete-callback).

Here is a small example what's new:

```
section <<< TextRow {
                  $0.placeholder = "Tag Name"
                  $0.value = tag
             }.willBeRemoved({ (textRow) in
                  // do your stuff here
            })
```

If you use **CocoaPods**, as a temporary solution just replace

```
pod 'Eureka'
```

with

```
pod 'Eureka', :git => 'https://github.com/AdamStreet/Eureka.git', :branch => 'multivaluedsection-delete-callback'
```